# How to expose only certain levels of a hierarchy in SSAS?

Tags: ssas, olap

So, this is an interesting problem:

I have hierarchies that are divided by a supplier. So for example, a geography hierarchy:

Client1 - Geography Hierarchy

- Supplier1

  - Global

    - NA

      - Michigan
    - Europe
- Supplier2

  - Global

    - NA

      - NJ

Is there a method in which I can expose only children of Supplier1 to certain users, and only children of Supplier2 to a different set of users? Specifically, a way without using roles?

Comment: What application is used to access the cube (Excel, custom app, etc.)?